# Accessory view in UITableView: view doesn't update

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm trying to add checkmarks to items when the user select rows in a table view. However, the view is not refreshed and the checkmarks do no show up:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell* oldCell = [self tableView:tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex inSection:0]];
    oldCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
    }

    UITableViewCell* newCell = [self tableView:tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    [tv deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
}
```

What could be a reason for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call cellForRowAtIndexPath directly on the tv object instead of through self to make sure you get a proper cell reference back:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *oldCell = [tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex inSection:0]];
    oldCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
    }

    UITableViewCell *newCell = [tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    [tv deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
}
```

Also make sure that in cellForRowAtIndexPath, you have this logic:

```
...
if (indexPath.row == selectedIndex)
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
else
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
...
return cell;
```

otherwise, a checkmark will remain on a cell after it scrolls off the screen and comes back on screen even after you've selected another cell.

Comment: Agreed, and from what I can see ALL of the code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath needs to go save the deselectRowAtIndexPath.   What should happen is when a row is selected, call [tv reloadData]; and let cellForRowAtIndexPath do it all.

Comment: Calling reloadData everytime you check or uncheck an item is a bad idea if you can just as easily set the checkmark manually without recreating every visible cell.

Comment: How different is it to call cellForRowAtIndexPath directly on tv or the way I was doing it? Anyways, it solved my problem, so thank you.

Comment: @Kamchatka: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198618/why-some-method-declarations-in-the-uitableviewdatasource-protocol-are-preceded-b/2198704#2198704) by Jasarien explains the difference.